# iOS return different subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, subclassing

I have a question about the following code:

```
 UICollectionViewCell *cell;

if (_peopleNotTasks == NO) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TaskCollectionCell";
     cell = (TaskCollectionCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PeopleCollectionCell";
     cell = (PeopleCollectionCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
//both cells have property x
//this does not work: 
cell.x = @"this is an awesome string";

return cell;
```

Why does that NOT work?

Both TaskCollectionCell and PeopleCollectionCell are subclasses of `UICollectionViewCell`.

**Expected:**

Access to the properties of TaskCollectionCell and PeopleCollectionCell.

If I make an outlet in the abstract class (which now is the superclass of TaskCollectionCell and  PeopleCollectionCell) I cannot connect it?
[image]

**EDIT**
found a way to find the outlet of the parent (abstract) subclass:

[image]

**EDIT**
Implemented solution with parent subclass:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ParentCell *cell;
if (_onlyUsersTasks == NO) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TaskCollectionCell";
    cell = (TaskCollectionCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PeopleCollectionCell";
    cell = (PeopleCollectionCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
cell.commonString = @"Thanks Jonathan";
return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What were you expecting to happen, and what did happen?

Comment: See edit  (sorry bout the missing info)

Comment: Show us the code of `PeopleCollectionCell` and `TaskCollectionCell` classes

Comment: They are too long? but both declare '@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *x;' in the header

Comment: @B-Man, how do you expect to access to `TaskCollectionCell` or `PeopleCollectionCell` custom properties, if those are casted implicitly as regular `UICollectionViewCell`? that has no such custom properties than your custom classes does, therefore you cannot see them via `cell`.

Comment: @holex thank you for your comment. I understand that part, i was merely looking for a way to have common properties, and a lot of ppl belowed helped with suggestions. Going with the abstract class :)

Comment: @B-Man, you can create a `protocol` for it, that could also help.

Comment: @holex another user below already suggested that method and I tried it and it worked fine. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the cell as a `UICollectionViewCell`, which does not have an `x property`. You are also casting the instance of the cell to your custom class, but the cell variable is still declared as a `UICollectionViewCell`. Instead, you could create a super class for `TaskCollectionCell` and `PeopleCollectionCell`, which declares the `x property`.

E.g.

```
NSString * const PeopleCollectionCellIdentifier = @"PeopleCollectionCell"; 
NSString * const TaskCollectionCellIdentifier = @"TaskCollectionCell";

CustomSuperClass * cell = (self.arePeopleNotTasks) ? [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:PeopleCollectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] : [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:TaskCollectionCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.x = @"this is an awesome string";


if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:PeopleCollectionCellIdentifier])
{
    PeopleCollectionCell * peopleCollectionCell = (PeopleCollectionCell *)cell;
    peopleCollectionCell.peopleOnlyProperty = nil;
}
else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:TaskCollectionCellIdentifier])
{
    TaskCollectionCell * taskCollectionCell = (TaskCollectionCell *)cell;
    taskCollectionCell.taskOnlyProperty = nil;
} 
return cell;
```

Comment: So I have to subclass UICollectionViewCell to make the common properties, and then subclass the new subclass to make the different properties?

Comment: How do I connect the outlets in the abstract class then? Xcode shows the actual subclass of the XIB in IB.

Comment: Change the Custom class in IB to the super class.

Comment: what about the outlets that are actually custom for the different XIBs? then i cannot connect those. see screenshot in edit

Comment: @Caleb and Jonathan I have accepted this as answer. I just implemented the protocol method and it is good, however the abstract parent subclass allows property customization in the .m file and requires less uphold (with the property method, all the subclasses need to conform to that protocol and you have to add <> everywhere so it gives a bit more overhead, though elegant). So now i am implementing the parent clas (although a bit different than the code you provided Jonathan. tell me if you want to see how i did)

Comment: @B-Man, that's great. I'm glad your problem is solved. Sure, I would like to see what you have now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply that the compiler only knows that `cell` Is a `UICollectionViewCell *` and that type doesn't have a property `x`. So, you need to give the compiler the information it needs. One way is to derive both your cell types from some common superclass that includes a property `x`, and then use that type for your `cell` ivar. A simpler way is to declare a protocol with that property, and the adopt that protocol in your cell types. Then you can simply specify the cell as a standard cell that adopts that protocol, like this:

```
 UICollectionViewCell<MyProperty> *cell;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `cell` as a `UICollectionViewCell` which does not have the property `x`.  The object oriented thing to do would be to create an abstract subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` that declares property `x`.  Then your `TaskCollectionCell` and `PeopleCollectionCell` can subclass this class.  You would then declare `cell` to be of this type of class.

Comment: How do I connect the outlets in the abstract class then? Xcode shows the actual subclass of the XIB in IB.

Comment: If `x` needs to be an IBOutlet, you could declare it an IBOutlet.  XCode should show any IBOutlets whether declared in a subclass or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you have created an instance on `cell` of the class `UICollectionViewCell` but when you do `cell.x` you still get an error, it could be that the class of the object `cell` does not have the `x` field or it is not accessible from that scope.

**I have the field declared on a subclass and still doesn't work, why?**

Suppose you have a base class called `Person` and then a subclass called `Children`.

If you declare a variable of type `Person` and store a `Children` object on it, you can't access `Children`'s fields that aren't declared on `Person`. It is a principle of the object paradigm.

Comment: even with init (see EDIT above) the property in still not accessible

Comment: `cell` *is* instantiated, even in the original question.

Comment: @Lucio i appreciate your effort, I do understand all that, I am just trying to find a way to make x accessible. The only way that makes sense is making a super-subclass of the UICollectionViewCell. Now the challenge remains how to connect the outlets of the superSubclass with the xibs of the actual subclasses

Comment: @B-Man use a protocol -- see my answer.

Comment: @Caleb just saw your answer. Not so experienced with protocols. need to google that.

Comment: @Lucio "instantiated" really isn't the right term -- classes are instantiated, variables are initialized. In any case, `cell` is assigned a value in both the `if` and `else` clauses, so by the time the OP tries to assign to `cell.x`, `cell` isn't nil.

Comment: @Caleb it says warning "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UICollectionViewCell <MyProperty> *' from 'TaskCollectionCell*'" when i deqeue TaskCollectionCell?

Comment: @Caleb Exactly. That is what I was trying to explain. I don't know where did I confused that on original post. BTW, create a chat room to keep discussing. This is becoming a mess..